# how to include a dropdownlist in every row and pass values to it in a kendo grid using client template

Tags: kendo-ui

How to  display dropdown list in every row using client template in kendo grid? 
I googled but i didnt find anything proper.I have a model with a string and a list and i want to bind it to a kendo grid using ajax binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by specifying editor for the column in grid. and define the editor property in view model.

Sample: your grid should be

```
<div id="gridId" data-role="grid"
                         data-scrollable="true"
                         data-row-template="your_RowTemplate"
                         data-editable="true" data-bind="source: GridSource" data-pageable="false"
                         data-columns="[       
                                        { 'title': 'Head' , 'field': 'yourField','editor':viewModel.yourEditor},
                                      ]">
                    </div>
```

Now you can define the editor in your view model like this

```
var viewModel = new kendo.observable({ 
GridSource:new kendo.data.dataSource({data:[],schema:{model:yourmodel}}) ,
DropdownSouce:[],//setyoursource 
yourEditor: function (container, options) {
        $('<input data-bind="value: ' + options.field + '" />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: viewModel.DropdownSouce,
            dataTextField: 'Text',
            dataValueField: 'Id'
        });
    }
});
```